# Optical zoom disable

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp

I am creating a kiosk application for use with Assigned Access mode, and I am looking for a way to either disable the optical zoom gesture entirely or be able to reset the zoom level using the JS APIs.  Is this possible?

Here's a description of [what the optical zoom gesture is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/guidelines-for-optical-zoom), specifically for UWP applications.

I've done some searching, and I am not seeing anything that lets me disable or reset pinch-zooming globally on my Microsoft Surface unit or in my kiosk users' Windows profile.

Here's what I've looked at so far:

1. Disable `Pinch Zoom` in mouse settings.  All the instructions I've found online [are for touch-pads](https://youtu.be/USuGH_YqmEk?t=90). The Microsoft Surface Pro 4 unit that I have does not have a Pinch Zoom setting in any of the mouse or touch settings.
2. Setting meta in the HTML to explicitly disallow zooming:  `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />`. This had no effect in the application. I am still able to pinch-zoom inside the application.
3. Explicitly set the application to not allow scaling: `window.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewScaling.trySetDisableLayoutScaling(true);` This also had no effect in the application. I am still able to pinch-zoom.
4. I have already loaded my application up as an Assigned Access app for my user, and I have confirmed that nothing "magical" happens to disable pinch-zooming in this kiosk-oriented environment.

I should also note, that I acknowledge the purpose of pinch-zooming.  Some users need/want to be able to zoom in from an accessibility standpoint. But I do need some way to reset the zoom level when a users session ends so that the next user doesn't see a "broken" UI.

Am I missing some obvious APIs that give me control over pinch zooming within a JS UWP app?

Comment: Also found this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh700412?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Views), indicating use of `-ms-content-zooming`.  No luck setting that either - still able to pinch-zoom.

Comment: Ahh, got it! I was setting -ms-content-zooming on the wrong element.  I ended up just setting it on the * CSS selector.

Comment: Working and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
* {
    -ms-content-zooming: none;
}
```

The [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh700412?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Views) shows the APIs available to control certain user interactions.  One of those is the CSS `-ms-content-zooming` property that can be used to disable the built-in optical zoom functionality.